# Querying a Facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search

Do you know a way to retrieve the posts of a group given a query as you can see in the image below?-> [Query Search example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3ih0.png)

This example returns us a list of posts related to our query, but we're trying to do that through any API.

So far we've tried this using **Graph API** getting the feed of the group, but feed doesn't support filtering by a query. Below you can see the type of GET request we're working with.

`graph.get('our_group_id?fields=feed.limit(500).fields(message, likes, type, comments.fields(like_count,message))'`

We've also tried using **SEARCH**, though Search is not able to deal with groups, so we can't retrieve the posts of a group based on a query, but some public posts. Finally we've tried also with FQL, but it doesn't appear to support query terms when searching posts of a group.

Thanks.